Can you remove the Honda ABS Module (electronics) without disconnecting the hydraulic ABS Pump?
In this video, Honda ABS Module TEAR DOWN what is casing this module to do bad on ALL HONDAs 2013 and above, you can see the user doing a tear down of the Honda ABS Module. My Honda Civic has this same module. I suspect it has the same problem.
Is it possible to remove the ABS module WITHOUT removing the pump. It would be desirable if I could remove this module, open it up, and verify if this problem exists without having to rebleed to the system (I lack one of those two-way OBDII systems that support bleeding).

Are you familiar with brake bleeding procedures? Abs repairs are normally not a diy project. The abs module most likely must be removed from the vehicle to work on the electronic circuit board. This means disconnecting brake lines (two inputs, four outputs?) to the abs module. Whether special   bleeding procedures are required when the abs module is removed/replaced is provided in service manuals. Abs servicing isn't do it yourself friendly.  As a safety issue, anyone performing diy brake repairs assumes all risks from incorrect repairs.

"As a safety issue, anyone performing diy brake repairs assumes all risks from incorrect repairs." thats true of all repairs

Not on the Honda Civics. It's just too hard to get to it -- but maybe if you remove the light and the headlight bracket. However, on the Accords there are multiple videos of this -- one linked below,

9th Gen Honda Civics look like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URYQ4jYbLjc
9th Gen Honda Accords look like this https://youtu.be/a2CROOcQ0zE?t=257

Even on my Civic, trying to take the whole thing out was a 5-10 minute job after unbolted and disconnected. There is just zero room where it's bracketed, and the above rigid brake cables make it even more difficult.

After you get it out, see this question on Electronics.StackExchange about performing the component-level repair by yourself

It depends on the orientation of the module. I watched a video of a guy working on an Accord. The module was fit tightly between the fender and the ABS pump. In order to get to it, you would have had to take the whole unit off. If your Civic is setup the same way, you'd have to remove the entire thing, then go through the bleeding procedure ... yes, the one you're not able to do yourself. Take a look at your module and see if you can get to it. I'm going to presume you're not going to be able to.

I actually removed the module without the pump. You need to take out the plastic window fluid tube. It just pops out. Removingvthe 3 bolts does help but doesnt really allow for too much movement because the hard lines are clipped. Removing them from the clip guides helps a bit. I also had to remove the wheel and the wheel well lining partially to get better access to the 2 bottom torx screws. It took a bit of time but removed the module without removing the pump and did not disconnect the break lines. Sent it out for repair and waiting to reinstall. Be prepared to spend some time and a second person to help guide from the top is helpful. It is doable.
